# Plotting a function, x = 1024

Tags: plotting

The function

```
 s12 = 1/(Log[2^x]*((7.537/(x^2)) + (30.148/((2 + x)^3))))
```

returns expected function values for `0 <  x < 10,000`

but the graph drops to 0 at `x = 1024`.

I am using the home version 9.0. Am assuming operator error unless told otherwise, but an older version plots without problems.

Any advice welcome.

Comment: Try `Plot[s12,{x,0,2000},WorkingPrecision->20]`. Also, please look through the [editing help](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) to learn how to format your code correctly.

Comment: Interestingly, redefining `s12` to be a function dependent on some argument `x` and in turn plotting the new function results in a graph that does not drop to 0 without specifying the working precision.

Comment: Both interesting comments. Will take the advice re formatting. My questions are usually basic so my ad hoc code has not been an issue to date. I see those days are over...Precision->20 worked, thanks.

Comment: @daniel Just an aside, in this case also `WorkingPrecision->15` works, which is normally smaller than `$MachinePrecision`. That's because arbitrary precision arithmetic is taking over which is apparently able to handle this at low precision. In general one has to experiment a bit and see what value works...

Comment: @VF1 This is very funny indeed!

Comment: BTW using `x*Log[2]` - which is equivalent to your `Log[2^x]` - fixes the problem too.

Comment: It works **without change** to the expression if I set  `f[x_]=s12` and do `Plot[f[x],{x,0,1030}]`.

Comment: The fact that `f[x_]` works but `s12` doesn't leads me to suspect that it's important for `Plot` to *not* evaluate the expression too early. E.g., if I replace `f[x]` by `Evaluate[f[x]]` in  `Plot`, the error re-appears. But *what* is happening with the unevaluated expression? One thing it could be doing is some pre-processing for `PlotLegends`. And coincidentally, that's exactly what has changed in version 9. So I'm inclined to blame `PlotLegends`. Again!? Or should I blame units support... I like that idea too...

Comment: It works by setting the option `Evaluated->False`

Comment: What I saw is just what @VF1 already wrote... and in addition it also works with `Plot[s12/.x->y,{y,0,1030}]`

Comment: @Jens excellent observation that it has to do with the sequence of evaluation - but how is that tied to the precision? This is why we need to know about internals.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is only a *possible* explanation, so read with care. First, we should try to reduce the problem. What I was curious about was that it's exactly 1024 when the graph drops. Therefore I assumed it must be connected to the `Log` and the `2^x` inside, and indeed look at this

```
Plot[1/Log[2^2^x], {x, 9.5, 10.5}]
```

(I used `2^x` so that the critical point is at 10.0)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

What I assume is that *Mathematica* compiles the expressions if possible. One could look at the `Trace` of such a `Plot` to see how many checks are done to find out, what kind of function is supplied and whether it has discontinuities etc. Beside other things, one can find options for `Compile` in the trace too. Let's try it

```
f = Compile[{{x, _Real}}, 1/Log[2^2^x]]
Table[f[x], {x, 10 - 10^-6, 10 + 10^-6, 10^-7}]
(*
  {0.00140888, 0.00140888, 0.00140888, 0.00140888,
   0.00140888, 0.00140888, 0.00140888, 0.00140888, 0.00140888, 
   0.00140888, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}
*)
```

This confirms the assumption and of course the plot of `f[x]` has the same drop.

The conclusion could be that *Mathematica* compiles expressions if possible. Obviously, defining a function with `g[x_]:=..` or using the `Evaluated` option does prevent this from happening.

As an additional note, @sebhofer mentioned in the first comment

> Try `Plot[s12,{x,0,2000},WorkingPrecision->20]`.

The question is, *why does this work*? Real numbers as used in compiled expressions have `$MachinePrecision` which is a value around 16. Try to set `WorkingPrecision` to 5 and you see that it's working anyway. The reason is in my opinion, that setting `WorkingPrecision` to any other value than `MachinePrecision` does prevent the call to `Compile`. Try it yourself

```
Plot[1/Log[2^2^x], {x, 9.5, 10.5}, WorkingPrecision -> #] & /@ {5, 20, MachinePrecision}
```

Comment: Just a small comment: 64-bit IEEE floating point presentation ("machine reals") has maximum value presentable, non-infinite value just under 2^1024. This is the reason *why* compiled/machine precision arithmetic fails at this point.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution, which tends to confirm @halirutan's explanation, is that the following produces the correct graph when compilation is turned off.

```
Plot[1/(Log[2^x]*((7.537/(x^2)) + (30.148/((2 + x)^3)))), {x, 0, 1200}, Compiled -> False]
```

Another confirmation is that if we turn on the tracking of machine overflow, we get the following:

```
cf = Compile[x, 1/(Log[2^x]*((7.537/(x^2)) + (30.148/((2 + x)^3)))), 
  RuntimeOptions -> {"CatchMachineOverflow" -> True}]
```

> During evaluation of In[25]:= CompiledFunction::cfn: Numerical error encountered at instruction 1; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation. >>

```
(* Out[25]= 195.251 *)
```

The expression `cf[x]` will produce the correct plot as well.

---

*Update*

From [Compiling Mathematica Expressions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/CompilingMathematicaExpressions.html):

> Similarly, functions like [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Plot.html) and [`Plot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Plot3D.html) use [`Compile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Compile.html) on the expressions you ask them to plot. Built-in functions that use [`Compile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Compile.html) typically have the option [`Compiled`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Compiled.html). Setting `Compiled -> False` tells the functions not to use [`Compile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Compile.html).