# Modified definition of Sin does not work in Plot

Tags: plotting

I don't know if this issue has been discussed before, if anyone know any related post, please let me know, thank you :)

`Unprotect` the function `Sin` and create a new definition for it:

```
Unprotect[Sin];
Sin[x_] := x^2;
```

Because `x_` matches any expression, then I think (naively) the system definition of `Sin` would never be applied.

```
{Sin[2], Sin[1.2], Sin[Sin]}
(*
   {4, 1.44, Sin^2}
*)
```

Every thing works as expected except for `Plot`:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi}]
```

[image]

I think it's related to the internal computation of `Plot`, I checked the mass output of `Trace` and found nothing useful.

I know it's stupid to modify a system symbol this way, but could you please give me some explanation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Part of the reason why modifying system symbols is such a bad idea is that they aren't bound to follow the same rules as ordinary symbols. In this case your modification was successful in one case and not another, suggesting that the behavior of `Sin` is to some extent hard-coded in the system. Modifying system symbols in such a way as to contradict their usual behavior carries the risk that your modifications may be unpredictably reverted at any time.

Comment: In this specific case, `Plot[Evaluated@Sin...` works, but Oleksandr's point is valid nevertheless.

Comment: I thought it might have to do with compilation (`Compile` your `Sin` and you get sine).  But `Method -> {Compiled -> False}` yields a sine curve.  However, `Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, WorkingPrecision -> 10]` and `Plot[(If[,,]; Sin[x]), {x, 0, 10}]` yield parabolas; but `Plot[(If[True,,]; Sin[x]), {x, 0, 10}]` yields sine.  Curious.  But I, too, think Oleksandr is on target.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured out that the [`Compiled`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Compiled.html) reference page has the usage wrong,* which misled my interpretation of the results of `Plot`.  Indeed I think the explanation is that `Plot` compiles the function expression.  In the compiled version, it makes internal calls to sine, which is the real sine, not your `Sin`.  It circumvents the normal pattern matching because it assumes `` System` `` functions are in fact system functions.  (I might rephrase OleksandrR's comment this way: system functions are in the context `` "System`" `` for a reason.)

In any case, this "fixes" your plot:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi}, Compiled -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

*The example should read

```
Plot[If[Exp[-x] == 0., 0, -1] + x/900, {x, 0, 1000}, Compiled -> False]
```

The syntax highlighting will mark `Compiled` in red, but it works nonetheless, as implied in [Compiling Mathematica Expressions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/CompilingMathematicaExpressions.html):

> Similarly, functions like [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Plot.html) and [`Plot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Plot3D.html) use [`Compile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Compile.html) on the expressions you ask them to plot. Built-in functions that use [`Compile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Compile.html) typically have the option [`Compiled`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Compiled.html). Setting `Compiled -> False` tells the functions not to use [`Compile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Compile.html).

Comment: +1 on both answers with `Compiled -> False`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks, and thanks for asking about the [other question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18126/plotting-a-function-x-1024).  It made give a second look at both.